# iOS App crashes on launch with Exception Type: EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, crash-reports

Can you please help me solving or getting to the root of this problem.
I found some question that were probable duplicate of this question but in all of them the crash was beacuase of some code inside their app, but in my case I noted that no code inside my app is executed (not even `func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool`) so I doubt if it is a duplicate of any other question.

**Basic Observation:** App crashes on launch.

**Pre-Condition:** when my device was connected to some wifi with not internet connection and MyApp was put to background and the Device was switched off for over a period of time (mostly 12 hours or more), Now switch on the device and try to click on the app icon to launch the app, but app crashes.

**Detailed analysis:** I tried to debug this issue but it is not recreated easily neither created every time following above preconditions, but it is really frustrating when it occurs because the app crashes every time we try to launch it (more than 10 times before it launches successfuly)

Attached are logs collected using XCode > Devices > Device Console

Name of application: **MyApp**

```
Aug  8 12:02:25 iPad kernel[0] <Notice>: xpcproxy[330] Container: /private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/19909EBC-CC8E-4099-BE03-65C2AF8F6466 (sandbox)
Aug  8 12:02:25 iPad kernel[0] <Notice>: Sandbox: MyApp(330) deny process-exec* /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/2B331890-D745-4149-BDDA-DE7EDECF118C/MyApp.app/MyApp
Aug  8 12:02:25 iPad locationd[64] <Notice>: Gesture EnabledForTopCLient: 0, EnabledInDaemonSettings: 0
Aug  8 12:02:25 iPad ReportCrash[331] <Error>: task_set_exception_ports(B07, 400, D03, 0, 0) failed with error (4: (os/kern) invalid argument)
Aug  8 12:02:25 iPad ReportCrash[331] <Notice>: ReportCrash acting against PID 330
Aug  8 12:02:25 iPad ReportCrash[331] <Notice>: Formulating crash report for process MyApp[330]
Aug  8 12:02:25 iPad com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (UIKitApplication:com.myCompany.myApp[0x7d94][330]) <Notice>: Service exited due to signal: Abort trap: 6
Aug  8 12:02:25 iPad ReportCrash[331] <Error>: Not saving crash log because we have reached the limit for logs to store on disk.  Sync or otherwise clear logs from /var/mobile/Library/Logs/CrashReporter to save new logs.
Aug  8 12:02:25 iPad ReportCrash[331] <Error>: Could not save crash report to disk!
Aug  8 12:02:25 iPad ReportCrash[331] <Error>: Incident Identifier: 5B7F8582-4388-4E91-A71B-896832561E6A
Aug  8 12:02:25 iPad ReportCrash[331] <Error>: CrashReporter Key:   4a3c78e803aea554f9700490a971b9a91e21bd63
Aug  8 12:02:25 iPad ReportCrash[331] <Error>: Hardware Model:      iPad3,6
Aug  8 12:02:25 iPad ReportCrash[331] <Error>: Process:             MyApp [330]
Aug  8 12:02:25 iPad ReportCrash[331] <Error>: Path:                /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/2B331890-D745-4149-BDDA-DE7EDECF118C/MyApp.app/MyApp
Aug  8 12:02:25 iPad ReportCrash[331] <Error>: Identifier:          MyApp
Aug  8 12:02:25 iPad ReportCrash[331] <Error>: Version:             ???
Aug  8 12:02:25 iPad ReportCrash[331] <Error>: Code Type:           ARM (Native)
Aug  8 12:02:25 iPad ReportCrash[331] <Error>: Parent Process:      launchd [1]
Aug  8 12:02:25 iPad ReportCrash[331] <Error>: Date/Time:           2017-08-08 12:02:25.455 +0530
Aug  8 12:02:25 iPad ReportCrash[331] <Error>: Launch Time:         2017-08-08 12:02:25.304 +0530
Aug  8 12:02:25 iPad ReportCrash[331] <Error>: OS Version:          iOS 8.1.2 (12B440)
Aug  8 12:02:25 iPad ReportCrash[331] <Error>: Report Version:      105
Aug  8 12:02:25 iPad ReportCrash[331] <Error>: Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Aug  8 12:02:25 iPad ReportCrash[331] <Error>: Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Aug  8 12:02:25 iPad ReportCrash[331] <Error>: Triggered by Thread:  0
Aug  8 12:02:25 iPad ReportCrash[331] <Error>: Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Aug  8 12:02:25 iPad ReportCrash[331] <Error>: Thread 0 Crashed:
Aug  8 12:02:25 iPad ReportCrash[331] <Error>: 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib           0x35f7adfc 0x35f66000 + 85500
Aug  8 12:02:25 iPad ReportCrash[331] <Error>: 1   libsystem_pthread.dylib          0x35ff8d32 0x35ff5000 + 15666
Aug  8 12:02:25 iPad ReportCrash[331] <Error>: 2   libsystem_c.dylib                0x35f1a904 0x35ed0000 + 305412
Aug  8 12:02:25 iPad ReportCrash[331] <Error>: 3   ...g_rt.asan_ios_dynamic.dylib   0x048cd9c0 0x4877000 + 354752
Aug  8 12:02:25 iPad ReportCrash[331] <Error>: 4   ...g_rt.asan_ios_dynamic.dylib   0x048ca10e 0x4877000 + 340238
Aug  8 12:02:25 iPad ReportCrash[331] <Error>: 5   ...g_rt.asan_ios_dynamic.dylib   0x048c4cd8 0x4877000 + 318680
Aug  8 12:02:25 iPad ReportCrash[331] <Error>: 6   ...g_rt.asan_ios_dynamic.dylib   0x048b971e 0x4877000 + 272158
Aug  8 12:02:25 iPad ReportCrash[331] <Error>: 7   dyld                             0x1fe7fa1a 0x1fe71000 + 59930
Aug  8 12:02:25 iPad ReportCrash[331] <Error>: 8   dyld                             0x1fe7fb20 0x1fe71000 + 60192
Aug  8 12:02:25 iPad ReportCrash[331] <Error>: 9   dyld                             0x1fe7cf9e 0x1fe71000 + 49054
Aug  8 12:02:25 iPad ReportCrash[331] <Error>: 10  dyld                             0x1fe7cf26 0x1fe71000 + 48934
Aug  8 12:02:25 iPad ReportCrash[331] <Error>: 11  dyld                             0x1fe7cdf2 0x1fe71000 + 48626
Aug  8 12:02:25 iPad ReportCrash[331] <Error>: 12  dyld                             0x1fe7d0c8 0x1fe71000 + 49352
Aug  8 12:02:25 iPad ReportCrash[331] <Error>: 13  dyld                             0x1fe72e3c 0x1fe71000 + 7740
Aug  8 12:02:25 iPad ReportCrash[331] <Error>: 14  dyld                             0x1fe763f4 0x1fe71000 + 21492
Aug  8 12:02:25 iPad ReportCrash[331] <Error>: 15  dyld                             0x1fe72222 0x1fe71000 + 4642
Aug  8 12:02:25 iPad ReportCrash[331] <Error>: 16  dyld                             0x1fe7203c 0x1fe71000 + 4156
Aug  8 12:02:25 iPad ReportCrash[331] <Error>: Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (32-bit):
Aug  8 12:02:25 iPad ReportCrash[331] <Error>:     r0: 0x00000000    r1: 0x00000000      r2: 0x00000000      r3: 0x00000000
Aug  8 12:02:25 iPad ReportCrash[331] <Error>:     r4: 0x00000006    r5: 0x386839dc      r6: 0x1fe98b60      r7: 0x04874020
Aug  8 12:02:25 iPad ReportCrash[331] <Error>:     r8: 0x00000000    r9: 0x386839dc     r10: 0x00000093     r11: 0x00000400
Aug  8 12:02:25 iPad ReportCrash[331] <Error>:     ip: 0x00000148    sp: 0x04874014      lr: 0x35ff8d37      pc: 0x35f7adfc
Aug  8 12:02:25 iPad ReportCrash[331] <Error>:   cpsr: 0x00000010
Aug  8 12:02:25 iPad ReportCrash[331] <Error>: Binary Images:
Aug  8 12:02:25 iPad ReportCrash[331] <Error>: 0xdb000 - 0x33a6fff MyApp armv7  <3341c8cdc7cc39d49fef358c4c48ef20> /var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/2B331890-D745-4149-BDDA-DE7EDECF118C/MyApp.app/MyApp
Aug  8 12:02:25 iPad ReportCrash[331] <Error>: 0x4877000 - 0x48e6fff libclang_rt.asan_ios_dynamic.dylib armv7s  <3fe196ea96903f038807adaca4005ced> /var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/2B331890-D745-4149-BDDA-DE7EDECF118C/MyApp.app/Frameworks/libclang_rt.asan_ios_dynamic.dylib
Aug  8 12:02:25 iPad ReportCrash[331] <Error>: 0x4de7000 - 0x4df2fff libswiftAVFoundation.dylib armv7s  <20c87a3924533c798c48642244a7a822> /var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/2B331890-D745-4149-BDDA-DE7EDECF118C/MyApp.app/Frameworks/libswiftAVFoundation.dylib
Aug  8 12:02:25 iPad ReportCrash[331] <Error>: 0x4e03000 - 0x5082fff libswiftCore.dylib armv7s  <7a6da327e6343442a09edeea51f6dcff> /var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/2B331890-D745-4149-BDDA-DE7EDECF118C/MyApp.app/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib
Aug  8 12:02:25 iPad ReportCrash[331] <Error>: 0x5315000 - 0x5320fff libswiftCoreAudio.dylib armv7s  <f800a3de6d733873ad4342aecedaaaf4> /var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/2B331890-D745-4149-BDDA-DE7EDECF118C/MyApp.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreAudio.dylib
.....Many other libraries (could not include due to text limit)
```

**Language used:** Swift3.0,

**Deployment target:**  8.0

Signed with **valid provisioning** and certificate.

> Updated - Tuesday, 8 August 2017 14:26:19 GMT+05:30

I also get following error in console some times

```
Aug  8 14:24:03 iPad amfid[172] <Error>:  SecTrustEvaluate  [leaf CriticalExtensions IssuerCommonName]
Aug  8 14:24:03 iPad kernel[0] <Notice>: xpcproxy[408] Container: /private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/B2F22E9F-350F-4936-98F0-9AE7DBFE7518 (sandbox)
Aug  8 14:24:03 iPad amfid[172] <Error>:  SecTrustEvaluate  [leaf CriticalExtensions IssuerCommonName]
Aug  8 14:24:03 iPad locationd[64] <Notice>: Gesture EnabledForTopCLient: 0, EnabledInDaemonSettings: 0
Aug  8 14:24:03 iPad amfid[172] <Error>:  SecTrustEvaluate  [leaf CriticalExtensions IssuerCommonName]
Aug  8 14:24:03 iPad amfid[172] <Error>:  SecTrustEvaluate  [leaf CriticalExtensions IssuerCommonName]
Aug  8 14:24:03 iPad amfid[172] <Error>:  SecTrustEvaluate  [leaf CriticalExtensions IssuerCommonName]
Aug  8 14:24:03 iPad amfid[172] <Error>:  SecTrustEvaluate  [leaf CriticalExtensions IssuerCommonName]
Aug  8 14:24:04 iPad amfid[172] <Error>:  SecTrustEvaluate  [leaf CriticalExtensions IssuerCommonName]
Aug  8 14:24:04 iPad amfid[172] <Error>:  SecTrustEvaluate  [leaf CriticalExtensions IssuerCommonName]
Aug  8 14:24:04 iPad amfid[172] <Error>:  SecTrustEvaluate  [leaf CriticalExtensions IssuerCommonName]
Aug  8 14:24:04 iPad amfid[172] <Error>:  SecTrustEvaluate  [leaf CriticalExtensions IssuerCommonName]
Aug  8 14:24:04 iPad amfid[172] <Error>:  SecTrustEvaluate  [leaf CriticalExtensions IssuerCommonName]
Aug  8 14:24:04 iPad amfid[172] <Error>:  SecTrustEvaluate  [leaf CriticalExtensions IssuerCommonName]
Aug  8 14:24:04 iPad amfid[172] <Error>:  SecTrustEvaluate  [leaf CriticalExtensions IssuerCommonName]
Aug  8 14:24:04 iPad amfid[172] <Error>:  SecTrustEvaluate  [leaf CriticalExtensions IssuerCommonName]
Aug  8 14:24:05 iPad MyApp[408] <Error>: assertion failed: 12B440: libxpc.dylib + 51947 [E83F44AC-48AF-3662-929E-FB7538661BB3]: 0x7d
```

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2004/tn2123.html